# How to remove charts from Excel using apache POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I will need to remove all the charts using Apache POI.

I tried using the following code :-

```
public XSSFSheet removeCharts(XSSFSheet sheet) {
    XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.getDrawingPatriarch();
    List<XSSFChart> charts = drawing.getCharts();
    charts.stream().forEach(v -> {
        v.getCTChartSpace().setNil();
    });
    return sheet;
}
```

But on saving and then opening the sheet it says corrupted XML.

Answer (score 2):

Please try the below code :

```
sheet.getDrawingPatriarch().getCTDrawing().setNil();
```

Comment: Works well in poi-ooxml:4.1.2. Thanks a lot!