# Copying Excel data cell by cell

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

I have a spring boot application that reads excel sheet data uploaded by the user and generates the json for the excel data. When the excel is huge ~3-8 MB (it has got charts also in it) i am getting the below error.

```
018-01-09T19:42:34.21+0530 [App/0] OUT 2018-01-09 14:12:34.212 ERROR 29 --- [io-63936-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory] with root cause
   2018-01-09T19:42:34.21+0530 [App/0] OUT java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory
   2018-01-09T19:42:34.21+0530 [App/0] OUT      at java.nio.Bits.reserveMemory(Bits.java:694) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
   2018-01-09T19:42:34.21+0530 [App/0] OUT      at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(DirectByteBuffer.java:123) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
   2018-01-09T19:42:34.21+0530 [App/0] OUT      at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(ByteBuffer.java:311) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
   2018-01-09T19:42:34.21+0530 [App/0] OUT      at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:195) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
```

As the file is becoming too big as it has got the charts data i would like to copy the file to another excel file without the chart data and then work on it.Can anyone please help me how can i do it using apache poi. So my basic ask is to copy all the excel sheet data cell by cell to another excel file.

Answer (score 0):

Someone asked a [enough close question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46646716/how-to-remove-charts-from-excel-using-apache-poi) some months ago : "How to remove charts from Excel using apache POI?".
Unfortunately, no answer about it.

To be honest, I don't exactly how to delete a chart.
However I can give you two ideas to solve your issue :

- if the charts are located in some specific tabs you can simply delete the tabs and recreate the workbook without.

For example to delete a tab :

```
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("chartSheet");
if(sheet != null)   {
     workbook.removeSheetAt(workbook.getSheetIndex(sheet));
}
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(copyFile);
workbook.write(output);`
```

- use a streaming API to read the big file.
  POI gives a sample to achieve it, [XLSX2CSV](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel/XLSX2CSV.java) :

> for reading very huge files, take a look at the sample XLSX2CSV which
>   shows how you can read a file in streaming fashion

You can also use the [event API](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#event_api) :

> It is intended for intermediate developers who are willing to learn a
>   little bit of the low level API structures. Its relatively simple to
>   use, but requires a basic understanding of the parts of an Excel file
>   (or willingness to learn). The advantage provided is that you can read
>   an XLS with a relatively small memory footprint.

POI provides multiple Event API : simple, record Aware Event API, SAX based API.
But note that all these streaming ways rely on a event-programming.
So it may bring a some complexity in the processings.

Comment: Thanks .. i was think if i can copy the content of my excel sheet to another new excel sheet row by row .that would eliminate  the charts.That would have been great.